# Usage of set command

Tags: tcl

I'd like to understand following code (was provided by third-party vendor) to that of simpler version.

```
#vendor code
set X "This is a string"
set $X {1.24 1.75}

set Y [set $X]

puts $X
puts $Y
```

```
#simpler code
set X "This is a string"
set Y {1.24 1.75}

puts $X
puts $Y
```

Both give same results. Is there any reasoning behind this extra assignment command?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason. Let me explain how the first block works.

```
set X "This is a string"
```

Assign string `This is a string` to the `X` variable.

```
set $X {1.24 1.75}
```

This will be evaluated by interpreter as:

```
set "This is a string" {1.24 1.75}
```

I mean, you will set the variable `This is a string` to the value `1.24 1.75` (yeah, in tcl you can use ANY string as a variable name).

```
set Y [set $X]
```

This will be evaluated by interpreter as:

```
set Y [set "This is a string"]
```

It means, that variable `Y` must be set equal to the value of the variable `This is a string` (which is `1.24 1.75`).

Thus, 2 your blocks are equal. Except that in the first block an additional variable `This is a string` will be defined. I consider this an undesirable definition.

Comment: There certainly are situations where you might want to hold the name of a variable in another variable, but this simple example is not one of them.

Comment: Most cases where you have the name of a variable in another variable, you use that name with `upvar`.